# Crawl S3 using Glue, adding some files to ignore, and still have their Athena data persist?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have a collection of S3 files that follow this format:

```
date=10001
   abc.json
   bcd.json
   cdf.json
date=10002
   ...
date=20001
   ...
```

These files are crawled by Glue to create a table in Athena (with the partition being date). Once an S3 file is created- it is never updated or deleted, so re-crawling it is redundant. To that end, I'm trying to have Glue ignore files that I know are already crawled.

I'm doing so by adding `10**` under the exclude patterns field- which is working- Glue isn't re-crawling those files, and the time to update my table is quartered. However, when I try to access anything from one of those ignored dates (e.g.- date=10001), I get the following error:

```
SELECT * FROM myAthenaTable WHERE date = '10001'

HIVE_PARTITION_SCHEMA_MISMATCH: There is a mismatch between the table and partition schemas. The types 
are incompatible and cannot be coerced. The column 'col1' in table 'myAthenaTable' is declared as type 
'int', but partition 'date=10001' declared column 'col2' as type 'struct<>'.
```

Curiously- if I remove the exclude pattern and rebuild my Glue table- it works just fine.

My goal is having Glue ignore date=10001 when crawling, but still be able to query it in Athena. To that end, how should I configure Glue?

I think these current output settings for Glue may be relevant:

```
When the crawler detects schema changes in the data store, how should AWS Glue handle table updates in the data catalog?
(yes) Update the table definition in the data catalog.

(yes) Update all new and existing partitions with metadata from the table.

How should AWS Glue handle deleted objects in the data store?
(yes) Mark the table as deprecated in the data catalog.
```

Comment: Does your JSON schema is fixed or it is variable i.e, will change in future?

Comment: There is variance in the json formats (some keys are missing in some files for instance), but I know all the possible fields that can be populated in the json file.

Comment: If your schema is fixed have you tried creating via Athena DDL create table statement and then add partitions via lambda s3 trigger -> alter table add partition?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to fix this issue. First, if the data was accidentally added, you can remove the data files that cause the difference in schema, drop the partition, and re-crawl the data. Second, you can drop the individual partition and then run MSCK REPAIR within Athena to re-create the partition using the table's schema. This second option works only if you are confident that the schema applied will continue to read the data correctly.